# Don't you sometimes hate the way the "m" character looks in your code?

Tags: language-agnostic, fonts, code-readability

Most of us write code using [monospaced fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) and the "m" character often (depending on the character combination) looks awful in monospaced fonts. It uses too many pixels in too little space.

I'm curious if anyone agrees with me on this.

Comment: This question seems to be a bit off-topic in my mind.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is off-topic, but it is totally subjective.

Comment: What font are you using? Try Consolas or Inconsolata.

Comment: I'm not sure who brought up the Consolas font thing first but, Thank You. It does look very good. Never knew about it. Made the question worth reading just for that. Thanks again.

Comment: Change your font. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just use a good monospace font that lets you distinguish the different characters.

[Verdana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdana) is quite good, though I personally never had too many problems with the default of [Currier New](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_%28typeface%29).

A good monospace font is [Consolas](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22e69ae4-7e40-4807-8a86-b3d36fab68d3&displaylang=en):

[image: Consolas example]

Comment: What's the name of that font?

Comment: I like ProFont.  I have no complaints about the m.

Comment: I love Verdana but I don't think it's a monospaced font.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm fond of using the **Consolas** font for coding.